# Slurm cluster: configure node where not all cores have equal number threads

Tags: configuration, cluster-computing, slurm, hpc

I've got a new node that I'm trying to add to my Slurm cluster. The cores on the new machine do not all have the same number of threads: 6 cores have 2 threads each and 4 cores have 1 thread each, a total of 16 CPUs. This is shown by `lscpu -e`:

```
CPU NODE SOCKET CORE L1d:L1i:L2:L3 ONLINE    MAXMHZ   MINMHZ
  0    0      0    0 0:0:0:0          yes 6300.0000 800.0000
  1    0      0    0 0:0:0:0          yes 6300.0000 800.0000
  2    0      0    1 1:1:1:0          yes 6300.0000 800.0000
  3    0      0    1 1:1:1:0          yes 6300.0000 800.0000
  4    0      0    2 2:2:2:0          yes 6300.0000 800.0000
  5    0      0    2 2:2:2:0          yes 6300.0000 800.0000
  6    0      0    3 3:3:3:0          yes 6300.0000 800.0000
  7    0      0    3 3:3:3:0          yes 6300.0000 800.0000
  8    0      0    4 4:4:4:0          yes 6300.0000 800.0000
  9    0      0    4 4:4:4:0          yes 6300.0000 800.0000
 10    0      0    5 5:5:5:0          yes 6300.0000 800.0000
 11    0      0    5 5:5:5:0          yes 6300.0000 800.0000
 12    0      0    6 6:6:6:0          yes 3600.0000 800.0000
 13    0      0    7 7:7:6:0          yes 3600.0000 800.0000
 14    0      0    8 8:8:6:0          yes 3600.0000 800.0000
 15    0      0    9 9:9:6:0          yes 3600.0000 800.0000
```

When appending to *slurm.conf* I'll usually just copy over info  from `lscpu`. For my new machine, the info is:

```
CPU(s):                          16
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-15
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              10
Socket(s):                       1
```

I appended to *slurm.conf* the following: `NodeName=MYNODE CPUs=16 SocketsPerBoard=1 CoresPerSocket=10 ThreadsPerCore=1`. However, this raised the following error:

```
error: NodeNames=MYNODE CPUs=16 match no Sockets, Sockets*CoresPerSocket or Sockets*CoresPerSocket*ThreadsPerCore. Resetting CPUs.
```

Internally, it seems like slurm expects nodes to have cores with all the same number of threads. How can I correctly configure *slurm.conf* for my new node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `SocketsPerBoard=1 CoresPerSocket=10 ThreadsPerCore=1` and just specifying `NodeName=MYNODE CPUs=16`. If you specify both `CPUS` and `Sockets`, `CoresPerSocket`, etc. Slurm will try to make sense of the `CPU` value. If you do not specify them, Slurm will accept the CPU value you give it.